# Normal bounded operator in Hilbert space, whose spectrum is real, is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let **$T$ be a bounded normal operator** in Hilbert space such that **the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is contained in the real axis.** By the Gelfand-Naimark theorem for commutative $C^*$-algebras the $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$ and $I$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\sigma(T)),$ the algebra of complex valued  continuous functions on $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R}.$ The operator $T$ corresponds to multiplication by $x$ in $C(\sigma(T)),$ therefore **$T$ is self-adjoint**.

I would like to prove that fact  in a straightforward way, but I could not come up with any idea.

When $T$ is a compact operator the proof is relatively easy. Assume by contradiction that $T^*-T\neq 0.$ Then one of the numbers $\lambda:=\pm{1\over 2}\|T^*-T\|\neq 0$ is the eigenvalue of the self-adjoint operator $B:={i\over 2}(T^*-T).$ Let $V_\lambda$ denote the eigenspace of the operator $B$ corresponding to $\lambda.$ As $T$ and $T^*$ commute with $B,$ the subspace $V_\lambda$ is invariant for $A={1\over 2}(T+T^*).$ The operator $T=A+iB$ restricted to $V_\lambda$ is of the form $A+i\lambda I.$ Therefore $\sigma(T)\subsetneq \mathbb{R},$ which gives a contradiction.

Comment: What does count as straightforward to you? The decomposition of a compact normal into an orthonormal system of eigenfunctions is the spectral theorem, so essentially the same argument as the one you sketched in the first paragraph.

Comment: It is not straightforward, but less abstract than making use of the maximal ideal space for commutative $C^*$-algebras. The spectral theorem for compact operators does not require abstract analysis. Just the fact that every nonzero number in the spectrum is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @MaoWao I have modified the proof for the case of compact $T.$ Now it does not make use of the full spectral theorem.

Comment: @MaoWao Eventually I have managed to come up with elementary solution.

Comment: I can only repeat what Martin said: Very nice indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know three ways, none really elementary.

1. By the Spectral Theorem. You have
   $$
   T=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda).
   $$
   Then, using the $\sigma(T)\subset\mathbb R$,
   $$
   T^*=\int_{\sigma(T)}\overline\lambda\,dE(\lambda)=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda).
   $$
2. If you know that for normal $T$ you have $$\tag1\overline{W(T)}=\overline{\operatorname{conv}}\sigma(T),$$ where $W(T)$ is the numerical range, you get easily that $T=T^*$. The problem is that the only proof of $(1)$ that I know uses the Spectral Theorem, so it is easier to do the argument directly as in the previous case.
3. If you have the Spectral Mapping Theorem (but again the only proof I know depends on the Spectral Theorem), you get that $T-T^*$ has real spectrum. So the selfadjoint operator $i(T-T^*)$ has imaginary spectrum, which implies that it is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that the spectral theorem (for two  commuting self-adjoint operators)  is a master key, that gives the conclusion instantly. But that 's not an answer I am after. For example the statement  "if $T$ is self-adjoint  and $\sigma(T)\subset [0,\infty),$ then $T$ is nonnegative" can be proved  using simpler tools.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to parse your definition of "simpler" and "straightforward". Your examples use $r(T)=\|T\|$, which requires machinery to be proven, and that the nonzero elements of the spectrum of a compact operator are eigenvalues of finite multiplicity, which also requires machinery to be proven. So it's not clear which machinery is acceptable and which one isn't.

Comment: I agree with you that's not clear. What is simple heavily  depends on a personal background. The stuff I have used is covered in a standard course of functional analysis. Spectral theorem, $C^*$-algebras, trace class operators, von Neumann algebras show up in more advanced courses.

Comment: Fair enough. Over my life I have had lots of heated discussions about what belongs and what doesn't to a "standard course in functional analysis", but I tend to agree with your criterion.

Comment: Thanks. Actually spectral theorem for normal operators or equivalently for two commuting self-adjoint operators you can hardly  find in textbooks.

Comment: Eventually I have managed to come up with elementary solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ be a normal operator such that $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R}.$ In particular the operator $iI-T$ is invertible. Consider $$U=(iI-T)(iI+T)^{-1}$$ Then $$\sigma(U)\subset \{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=1\}\setminus\{-1\}$$
Indeed, let $\lambda\notin  \{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=1\}\setminus\{-1\}.$ Then $$U-\lambda I =[(iI-T)-\lambda(iI+T)](iI+T)^{-1}\\
= [i(1-\lambda)-(1+\lambda)T](iI+T)^{-1}=(1+\lambda)\left [ i{1-\lambda\over 1+\lambda}- T\right  ](iI+T)^{-1}
$$
It can be verified easily that $i(1-\lambda)(1+\lambda)^{-1}$ is not real, hence the the operator $U-\lambda I$ is invertible.
Indeed assume  that $i(1-\lambda)(1+\lambda)^{-1}=t.$ Thus
$\lambda =(i-t)(i+t)^{-1}.$ If $t$ is a real number then $|\lambda|=1.$

The inverse operator also satisfies $\sigma(U^{-1})\subset \{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=1\}.$
The operator $U$ is normal, therefore its norm is equal to the spectral radius, i.e. $\|U\|= 1.$ Similarly $\|U^{-1}\|=1.$
Thus for any $x\in \mathcal{H}$ we have
$$\|x\|=\|U^{-1}Ux\|\le \|Ux\|\le \|x\|.$$ Therefore $\|Ux\|=\|x\|,$ which implies that $U$ is a unitary operator. We have
$$T=i(I-U)(I+U)^{-1}.$$ The formula is well defined as $-1\notin\sigma(U).$
The formula implies  that $T$ is selfadjoint as
$$T^*=-i(I+U^{-1})^{-1}(I-U^{-1}) =-i(I+U)^{-1}(U-I)=i(I-U)(I+U)^{-1}=T$$

Comment: Very nice! $ \ $

Answer (score 2):

In deference to the contentious nature of the sentence "to prove a fact in a
straightforward way", let me begin by listing the tools we will use:

1. The spectral radius $r(T)$ of a normal operator $T$ coincides with its norm.
2. For every operator $T$, one has that $\sigma (T+\lambda )=\sigma (T)+\lambda $.  Notice that this may be considered as a baby
   version of the Spectral Mapping Theorem.
3. An operator $T$ on a complex Hilbert space is self-adjoint if and only if
   $
     \langle T(x),x\rangle \in {\mathbb  R},
     $
   for every $x\in  H$.

If you consider these as "straigtforward facts", please keep reading!

In view of (3) above, let us  fix  $x\in H$, which we assume WLOG to be a
unit vector, and we write
$$
  \langle T(x),x\rangle =a+ib,
  $$
with $a$ and $b$ real.  We then have for every $c\in {\mathbb  R}$ that
$$
  a^2+b^2+2bc+c^2 =
  |a+ib+ic|^2= $$$$ =
  \big|\big \langle (T+ic)x,x\big \rangle \big|^2  \leq \|T+ic\|^2= r(T+ic)^2 = $$$$ =
  \sup \{|\lambda |^2: \lambda \in \sigma (T+ic)\} = \sup \{|\lambda +ic |^2: \lambda \in \sigma (T)\} = $$$$ =
  \sup \{\lambda ^2 +c^2: \lambda \in \sigma (T)\} =   c^2+\sup \{\lambda ^2: \lambda \in \sigma (T)\}.
  $$
Cancelling out the term $c^2$, we get
$$
  a^2+b^2+2bc \leq    \sup \{\lambda ^2: \lambda \in \sigma (T)\}.
  $$
Now,  since this holds for every $c\in {\mathbb  R}$, one necessarily has that $b=0$, as required.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice indeed.