# Matrix satisfying simple equation is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a $n\times n$ complex matrix $A$ holds $A+A^{*} = A^2A^{*}$, where $A^{*}$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. How can we show that $A$ is normal, that is, $AA^{*}=A^{*}A$?

I was asked about this problem in linear algebra class but couldn't answer it.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360). Please [edit] your question to explain where you encountered this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's [a quick guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) (if nothing else, read up the part on ["avoiding no-clue questions"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conclusion is valid for a bounded operator $A$ on a Hilbert space.
By applying the complex conjugation we get
$$A+A^*=A(A^*)^2\quad (*)$$  Then
$$A^2+AA^*=A(A+A^*)=A^2(A^*)^2\quad $$
Therefore  $$A^2=A^2(A^2)^*-AA^*$$ i.e. $A^2$ is self-adjoint. Hence $(*)$  takes the form
$$A+A^*=A^3 $$ and $A^*=A^3-A.$ Thus $A^*$ commutes with $A.$

We will prove that $A^*=A.$
It suffices to show that $\sigma(A)\subset \mathbb{R}$ [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416162/normal-bounded-operator-in-hilbert-space-whose-spectrum-is-real-is-self-adjoin).
As $A^2$ is self adjoint $(*)$ implies that $A+A^*=A^3.$ Hence $A^3$ is self adjoint as well. Let $\lambda\in \sigma(A).$ Then $\lambda^2\in \sigma(A^2)$ and $\lambda^3\in \sigma(A^3).$ As both operators are self adjoint we get $\lambda^2,\lambda^3\in \mathbb{R}.$ Thus $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: That would be enough but I don't see why the right hand side commutes with 
$A^{*}$.
$A^{*}[(A^{*})^2-I]^{-1}A^{*}=AA^{*}.$
Multiplying on the right with $A^{*}$ I don't get again $AA^{*}.$

Comment: $A^*$ and $(A^*)^2-I$ commute with $A^*.$ Hence $[(A^*)^2-I]^{-1}$ commutes with $A^*.$ Finally the product of $[(A^*)^2-I]^{-1}$ and $A^*$ commutes with $A^*.$

Comment: Thank you very much! The only part that is not clear is why $A^{*}v=0$ implies $v=0$. Can you please clarify this important step in the proof?

Comment: $A^*v=0$ implies $(A^*)^2v=0.$ But $(A^*)^2v=v.$ Hence $v=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Any ideas how to modify this proof if $A$ is assumed to be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space? Because then it is not evident that $(A^*)^2-I$ is invertible.

Comment: The answer has been re-edited and in order to cover the case of bounded operators.